# phpmailer & in subject coming in as &amp;

Tags: php, phpmailer, ampersand

I am sending emails using PHPMailer and through my gmail account with SMTP.  It all works except when there is an `&` in the subject, then in my inbox the subject has `&amp;`

Any way to make this not happen?  I've tried setting the charset and encoding the subject.

My code is below

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug  = false;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "myusername@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password
$mail->SetFrom('from@somesite.com', 'From Person');
$mail->AddReplyTo("from@somesite.com", "From Person");
$mail->Subject    = 'An example with a & in the middle';
$mail->MsgHTML('Some text to send');
$mail->AddAddress('myusername@gmail.com');
$mail->Send()
```

Thank You

Comment: Looks like a bug in PHPMailer to me.  Can you post the raw message itself, as received?

Comment: The subject in the raw format has the &amp; in it.  I'm able to look at the message in my sent folder as well and it has the &amp; also.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code, let me know if it helps.

```
$mail->Subject    = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($_POST['subject'])."?=";
```